# Sending string from Obj-C client using socket rocket to Java server

Tags: java, objective-c, sockets, base64, client-server

**Client side:** Just using socket rocket

```
-(void)start
{
    self.socket = [[SRWebSocket alloc] initWithURL:_serverURL];
    self.socket.delegate = self;
    [self.socket open];
}

- (void)webSocketDidOpen:(SRWebSocket *)webSocket
{
    NSLog(@"webSocketDidOpen!");
    NSString *string = @"Hello, server!";
    NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSError *err;
    [self.socket sendData:data error:&err];
    if (err) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@",err);
    }
}
```

Delegate method works well

> 2017-05-11 22:40:53.746 Client[1787:96062] webSocketDidOpen!

**Server side:**
Using scanner for input stream.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream,"UTF-8");
String data = scanner.useDelimiter("\\r\\n\\r\\n").next(); 
Matcher get = Pattern.compile("^GET").matcher(data);
if (get.find()) {
    Matcher match = Pattern.compile("Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)").matcher(data);
    match.find();
    String clientKey =  (match.group(1) + "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11");
    String digest =  DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1").digest(clientKey.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    byte[] response = ("HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n"
                        + "Connection: Upgrade\r\n"
                        + "Upgrade: websocket\r\n"
                        + "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + digest
                        + "\r\n\r\n")
                        .getBytes("UTF-8");
     outputStream.write(response, 0, response.length);
     outputStream.flush();


     scanner.useDelimiter(""); //then, reading all input data
     System.out.println("input stream: ");
     while (scanner.hasNext())
     {
         System.out.print(scanner.next());
     }
     System.out.println("input done");
}
```

On logs I have just

> input stream:
>
> ��{~E�3)�Re�

I think I must use some decoding, but how exactly can I do it without closing socket? How can I understand when I must decode string, when encrypted input stream has no delimiters?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `SRWebSocket`, but since I see `MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1")`, did you encrypt it?

Comment: I think, SRWebSocket does it. I just need to disable encryption or decrypt message on server, but I can't figure out how